# Please take a look at this code. it works fine on Access table but after linked to SQL Database table is produced error

Tags: sql, syntax

```
strQuery = "SELECT tblAppointments.AppID, tblAppointments.ReservedDate, tblAppointments.AppointDate, tblAppointments.AppointTime, Left([tblSchedule].[DoctorsName],5) AS Doctor, tblSchedule.DoctorsName" _
& " FROM tblSchedule INNER JOIN tblAppointments ON tblSchedule.DoctorsID = tblAppointments.DoctorsID " & "WHERE (((tblAppointments.AppointDate)>=Date()));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
```

how can I correct the SQL syntax to string to run on Link SQL Table on Access project

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Show us the strQuery contents.

Comment: SQL database? Which one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the WHERE clause `"WHERE (((tblAppointments.AppointDate)>=Date()));` SQL doesn't have a "Date()" function - use GETDATE instead